# How do I iterate through an array without having my iterator reset to 0 with each button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iterator

I have an array storing words.  I need to be able to access one word each time a button is clicked.  The next time the button is clicked I need to be able to access the next item in the array.

I had this working great in vb.net but in asp.net/vb.net, my public variable resets to zero each time the button is clicked so I get the same item every time.

```
Partial Class Residential
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public NextNum As Integer

    Private Sub ProducePurpleSentence()

        Dim calltoactionArray(3) As String
        calltoactionArray(0) = "Go!"
        calltoactionArray(1) = "Run!"
        calltoactionArray(2) = "Jump!"
        calltoactionArray(3) = "Yell!"

        PurpleSentence = ""

       'This should reset NextNum to 0 once the last array element is reached.
        If NextNum > calltoactionArray.Length + 1 Then
            NextNum = 0
        Else
        End If

        PurpleSentence = calltoactionArray(NextNum)

       'NextNum should iterate here.        
        NextNum = NextNum + 1

        TxtOutput.Text = PurpleSentence
    End Sub

Private Sub BtnPurpleRedo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPurpleRedo.Click
        Call ProducePurpleSentence()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I need "PurpleSentence" to be the first array element of calltoactionarray the first time I click BtnPurpleRedo, the sencond element the second time I click it and so on.  I also need it to go back to the first element once the last element has been output.

Comment: On the web, each page load is like a opening a new application. You need to store your variable in a special container (like session variable) or in the page itself if you want to keep the value.

Comment: The web is _stateless_, so you have to manage that yourself. Read [this](https://medium.com/@KevinHoffman/the-15-factors-of-asp-net-stateless-processes-b2977f44f2b2) article for some possible options

Comment: minor remark: shouldn't this line `If NextNum > calltoactionArray.Length + 1 Then` be -1 instead?

Comment: Yes AConfusedSimpleton, you are right. it should be "If NextNum > calltoactionArray.Length - 1 Then"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can persist data between calls to the page in the "session state". (There are other places it can be saved, which are better in some ways in some situations.)

First you have to enable session state in web.config: add the following inside the  `<configuration>` element:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
</system.web>
```

Then you can use it to save your variable:

```
Private Sub ProducePurpleSentence()

    Dim calltoactionArray = {"Go!", "Run!", "Jump!", "Yell!"}
    Dim nextNum As Integer = 0

    If Session("nextNum") IsNot Nothing Then
        nextNum = DirectCast(Session("nextNum"), Integer)
    End If

    Dim PurpleSentence = calltoactionArray(nextNum)

    nextNum = (nextNum + 1) Mod calltoactionArray.Length
    Session("nextNum") = nextNum

    TxtOutput.Text = PurpleSentence

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I will give this a try.  I actually got it to work by storing nextNum in an invisible textbox but I like this better.